# python add custom __setattr__ and __getattribute__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a class in python in which variable assignment and retrieval need to be done through a different class with its logic for set_value and get_value.

**MyObj** class gives the logic for set_value and get_value

```
Class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
```

The user creates a **MyClass** object and sets/gets values to these variables, but the **MyObj** class will be 100% abstracted from the user.

```
class MyClass:
    item1 = MyObj()
    item2 = MyObj()
    item3 = MyObj()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print(f"set logic :: {key}, {value}")
        # key.set_value(value)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print(f"get logic :: {item}")
        # return item.get_value()
```

**Myclass** will behave like any other python class but with setter and getter logic coming from **MyObj**.

```
cls = MyClass()
cls.item1 = 10 # Issue: this should not replace variable value from class object.
print(cls.item1) # Issue: this should not return class object
```

Issue:

1. Currently, this will be done through the `__setattr__` and  `__getattribute__` methods, but I can't get the code working as the parameters are in the string.
2. I don't want to manually type getter and setter for each variable in **MyClass**.
3. User should be able to read and write variables of **MyClass** like standard python class variables.
4. https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict this lib does something similar but not what I am looking for.

Comment: It seems like you are describing [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#managed-attributes), but you're using different methods. It's not clear (to me) if you need something other that what descriptors do.

Answer (score 0):

While this *can* be done with clever use of `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__`, it's going to be more trouble that way. What it sounds like you want is [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ''

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = '__MyObj_' + name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self._name, value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self._name, 0)

class MyClass:
    item1 = MyObj()
    item2 = MyObj()
    item3 = MyObj()
```

Suppose we have a `MyClass` instance called `x`. When we try to access `x.item1`, Python notes that `x.__dict__` (the dictionary of instance variables for `x`) does not contain `item1`. So instead it looks at `x`'s class, which is `MyClass`. `MyClass.item1` *is* defined, so Python is going to return that. However, we accessed it as an instance variable, so in fact what Python is going to give us is `MyClass.item1.__get__(x, MyClass)`. So whenever we write `x.item1`, Python will call `__get__` on `MyObj`. Likewise for `item2` and `item3`. Note that this is the same technique that Python uses to bind `self` on function objects inside of the class. The function type itself has a `__get__` which returns a bound method object, not the original function. That's why `x.some_method(1)` is equivalent to `MyClass.some_method(x, 1)`. It's because it's *actually* equivalent to `MyClass.some_method.__get__(x, MyClass)(1)` which translates into the former.

Similarly, when we try to assign to `x.item1` with `x.item1 = new_value`, Python will call `MyClass.item1.__set__(x, new_value)`, so there's your setter. We can also write a `__del__` which would work if we tried to use the `del` syntax with `x.item1`, though you didn't mention deleters, so I omit it here.

The only point of note is that, using this technique, there is only one `MyObj` for each field on the class, *not* one for each instance. So, in the example I posted above, I use `__set_name__` and a clever naming convention to place the backing field in the `MyClass` instance's `__dict__`. If all you want to do is return a synthetic value and not actually have a backing field, you won't need that. And depending on your use case, [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) might work for you and save you some typing.

Comment: One issue I see with this solution:
Let's say I add a method `def ok(self): print("ok")` in `MyObj` and then try to access it from `MyClass`:

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    cls = MyClass()
    cls.item1 = 10
    print(cls.item1)
`

now trying to access ok method from MyClass `__init__` ::
`def __init__(self):
        members = [getattr(self, attr) for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith("__")]
        print(members[0].ok())`
print line will give error as item1 is int

Comment: Basically, I want the user to get only int, but from Inside `MyClass`, I want to control the `MyObj` class fully.

Comment: My above comments requirement can be fulfilled by writing getter and setter for each variable of the class, but there are many variables I don't want to write getter and setter for all.

Comment: There is no "inside the class" in Python. Methods defined inside the class aren't special. They have a first argument that is conventionally called `self`, but that's not a keyword. As far as the inside of the function is concerned, `self` is the name of an ordinary variable that happens to point to an instance of a particular class.